# Push Notification Device Token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have a live app. in apple store that implements a push notification procedure. As known I communicate with my server to send and save device tokens.

My server is receiving device tokens correctly for some devices(Requests) and also receives null values for some other devices.

How is that could be possible in any case?!

Comment: It's possible that for some devices the registration fails and your app doesn't detect this failure and sends an empty device token to your server. You should post your relevant application code.

Comment: Can you list registration failure reasons?

Comment: It may have been a temporary network problem (perhaps the device was disconnected when your app tried to register to APNS).

Comment: problem happen more often than to be just a network problem. network problem on APNs register and not when communicating with my server!

Comment: Hey @hasan83 i am also facing a same issue now not getting some device tokens have implemented all delegates. So did you found any solution??

Comment: Delete provisioning profiles from device. Settings > General > Profiles. then try again. you are supposed to delete your app. push notification profile.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have a bug in your code, the device never generates a null token, or you have failed to implement the following delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
```

If this delegate gets called then you could/should implement a retry algorithm that retries to re-register for the APN token a few times.

Comment: my app retry to register the device in every user login. but that does not seems the problem. I will check that. but, problem appear more often than a few times.

Comment: That's not what I mean - when you call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: then the device may not be able to generate the APN token for you at that moment. You must implement the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError delegate to find out if this is the case. If so then call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:, and again if necessary, and again if necessary. That is what I mean by a retry algorithm. Perhaps you could try again immediately, if that too fails, then wait a few seconds then try again, if that fails wait 30 seconds and try again etc.

Comment: it was our client device. we used to send him development versions of the app with profile that does not allow push notification. in somehow when he installed the app. from the store application kept using profiles installed on device!? explanations?

Comment: also, what should I do now with this question?

Comment: My app also facing same issue that is neither app is getting device token for APNS nor the method didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithErro is getting called on some devices when we are testing app using Ad-Hoc distribution. Please help me.

Comment: My app also facing same issue (though I have implemented and added delegate methods to support APNS on iOS 8 and earlier versions) that is neither app is getting device token for APNS nor the method didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithErro is getting called on some devices when we are testing app using Ad-Hoc distribution. We have done following when trying to resolve this issue 1) Tried after deleting provisioning profiles on such devices from Setting app > General > Profiles. 2) Checked after Re-installing the app but did not resolved the issue. Please help me.